Catalyst app UTF-8 encoding doesn't seem to be working
I've noticed that my Catalyst app doesn't seem to be handling non-standard characters correctly - I first noticed this when the RTF text editor app I was using replaced " characters with the “angled” kind at the start / end of a string.  I've agonised over this, and have thrown up a new blank Catalyst app with the following index page:
sub index :Path :Args(0) {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    # Hello World
    #$c->response->body( $c->welcome_message );
    $c->response->body("<h1>Hello World, where's the nearest café</h1>");
    $c->log->debug(sprintf("encoding: %s", $c->encoding->mime_name));
}

This gives the following in my browser:

However my Catalyst is version 5.90131, which should be encoding UTF-8 by default, in fact the debug message in the routine gives me: [debug] encoding: UTF-8
Browser shows UTF-8 too in the headers:

Started pulling my hair out a bit - I'm sure I'm missing something totally obvious, please could someone point me in the right direction!  Thanks so much.
I have added use utf8 to the controller, which fixed the page text:

However, input form fields are still not encoding:

Entering that form gives:


Do you save the source code as UTF-8? Did you tell Perl that the source code contains UTF-8 characters by including use utf8;?

Thanks @choroba, that seems to have worked on the text on the page, but input text fields still don't encode - will edit the post to reflect.

What is the output of sprintf("%vX", $input), where $input contains the problematic input string. Sounds like they never got decoded. Don't know if you can ask Catalyst to do that for you, or if you have to do it yourself.

That gives 63.61.66.E9 - didn't know about that sprintf flag, thanks!  I thought, from the docs, the encoding being baked into Catalyst now meant it did the decoding for you.

That could be "café" as decoded text (as a string of Unicode Code Points), meaning the same as use utf8; my $input = "café";.  It could also be "café" encoded using iso-8859-1 or cp1252, but that's unlikely based on context. (You can test using ♠ to be sure.) So this means means you have exactly what you want.

Thanks @ikegami, I did actually use the heart character, as per here, but still not getting the right results - I will try to modify my tests and original post to show this tomorrow: https://metacpan.org/dist/Catalyst-Runtime/view/lib/Catalyst/UTF8.pod#UTF8-in-GET-Query-and-Form-POST

Re "but still not getting the right results", You question said you weren't getting the right string, but you showed that you are. No idea what you do with the string afterwards since you didn't say anything about that. If you have a problem with that, you will need to ask a question about that. But as it stands, you get the correct value. (Given the lack of any problem to solve, I voted to close as Not reproducible.)

Understood @ikegami, and apologies for that.  The original question was an attempt to simplify things, and I stupidly hadn't realised that the static content I put on the page was encoded differently to the input from a user; it's user input that I'm struggling with.
I've tried with the value Heart - ♥ in the input and get in the debug: Heart - ÔÖÑ - if I try to write this to the database, that is the value that gets written too.

Again, I have no idea how you output that, so it tells me nothing. What does sprintf("%vX", $input) give?

Many apologies, yes, that would have helped - this gives: 48.65.61.72.74.20.2D.20.2665 - the heart on its own obviously just gives 2665.

With apologies (and help from @ikegami), I've worked out that there was a system encoding issue preventing some of this working correctly, or seeming to work correctly.  Still got to get the database portion working, but that will be another, hopefully less confused question if I get to that bit.
